# Dockerfile: is it possible to reference overridden entrypoint and cmd?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to build a image using mysql 5.6 from [here](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/) as a base image. I need to do some initialization before the database starts up, so I need to override the entrypoint:

```
# Stuff in my Dockerfile
...
COPY my-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["my-entrypoint.sh"]
```

My entrypoint is fairly simple, too:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Running my-entrypoint.sh"
# My initialization stuff here
...
# Call mysql entrypoint
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld
```

This seems to work, but I'd rather not have to hard-code the mysql entrypoint in my script (or my Dockerfile). Is there a way to reference the overridden entrypoint in my Dockerfile, so that it is available to my entrypoint script? Something like this, perhaps?

```
COPY my-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["my-entrypoint.sh", BASE_ENTRYPOINT, BASE_CMD]
```

Answer (score 1):

It has to appear in somewhere in someway, otherwise you can't get such information.

- Option 1: use an `ENV` for previous entrypoint in `Dockerfile`, and then refer to it in your own entrypoint.sh:

  Dockerfile:

  ```
  FROM alpine:3.3

  ENV MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT "/usr/bin/mysql mysqld"
  ADD entrypoint.sh /
  ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
  ```

  Entrypoint.sh:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  echo $MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT
  ```
- Option 2: just pass previous entrypoint command as parameter to your entrypoint:

  Dockerfile:

  ```
  FROM alpine:3.3

  ADD entrypoint.sh /
  ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.sh"]
  CMD ["/usr/bin/mysql mysqld"]
  ```

  Entrypoint.sh:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh

  echo $1
  ```

Personally I prefer option #1.

Comment: Both options appear to still require it to be hard-coded, just in the Dockerfile now.

Comment: Pass it in at runtime `docker run ... -e MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT=<something> ...`

Comment: Thanks for your info guys, I believe it has to appear in somewhere in some way, and I don't think pass it at runtime is a good idea, this env variable is not different for each runtime, or for different platform on which you're going to run this container,  it has been certain at build stage,  passing it at runtime does nothing more but adding extra work.

Comment: @RobWatts, as far as I know there's no pre-defined variable for each entrypoint, and I don't see the necessary because it could be overridden for many many times in real practices, when people overrides it, it's for sure that they want their own way to start the container. Starting mysqld is just last step of your own logic, and the command of starting mysql is some info contained in the base image, so I think it's the appropriate place to define it in your Dockerfile. This is my understanding and I'll appreciate if you can share me with other ideas. Have a nice day:-)

Comment: @shizhz he specifically said he doesn't want to hard code it. What other option is there than pass at runtime? :p

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

Just pass it in after you specify your image, everything after that becomes the `CMD` and appended to your `ENTRYPOINT`. So...

```
# Stuff in my Dockerfile
...
COPY my-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
ENTRYPOINT ["my-entrypoint.sh"]
```

Then `docker run ... image <your-entrypoint-etc>` then just have your custom entrypoint pick up the 1st arg to it and use that however you need.

Second way, just pass it as an environment variable at runtime.

`docker run ... -e MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT=<something> ...`

And in your entrypoint script refer to the env variable `... $MYSQL_ENTRYPOINT ...`